# ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to export array that I created to ".csv" file but I am getting an error from a title.

I create array with:

```
map_table = np.zeros((broj_stanja, broj_akcija)) #(500 x 6)
```

My export code:

```
np.savetxt("test.csv", map_table, delimiter=",")
```

Array looks like:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

And filled array looks like:

```
[[  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
    0.        ]
 [ -2.32127743  -2.13656866  -2.32039787  -2.13702084  -1.83910189
  -11.1362683 ]
 [ -1.84018441  -1.35777159  -1.83913505  -1.36492166  -0.57891593
  -10.35787171]
 ...
 [ -2.13231639  -1.35809409  -2.06537874  -2.17259228 -10.74950563
  -10.88689193]
```

[Full code example.](https://github.com/jskako/Q-Learning/blob/master/code.py)

Comment: Can you post your full code with desired output, or [mcve]?

Comment: @zipa I am sorry I was trying to keep it to minimum to be easier for understand, I update post with github link to code

Comment: In your code you are saving `ucenje` which is a function, not an array.

Comment: A minimum example helps only if it reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Saving a function returns such error:

```
def ucenje():
   return np.array((1, 1, 1))
np.savetxt('test.txt', ucenje)
```

> ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

Take note that an empty file is created on disc.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote wrong variable there, thank You for pointing that out, now everything works as it should